# How to stop disabling the submit button in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, submit

I have a form In which I am printing values basically its an update form, the case is user can not send empty fields in update. But the problem is i have two fields which are actually `password` and `confirm-password` I am not getting the values of them so their search box would be **empty**.

**Case- 1**

Now How can I send all values except password and confirm password in update form and throw errors if anything is empty apart from `password` and `confirm password`

**Case - 2**

How can do this if user type something in search box of `password` and then rub it and all the fields of form go but except password and confirm password.

In short I want to send all the filled fields apart from `password` and `confirm password`, and in any case if they are filled they should be posted too.

I am sharing my complete form, I did apply validtions but the thing is because of empty box of `password` and `confirm password` My submit button is disable.

```
<form class="col-md-8" name="updateprofileForm" ng-submit="update_profile()" novalidate>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.username.$invalid && !updateprofileForm.username.$pristine" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Enter a valid Username</p>
                                <label for="text">Full Name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="username" id="name" type="text" ng-model="profileData.username" ng-maxlength="40" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.email.$invalid && !updateprofileForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Enter a valid email</p>
                                <label for="text">Email:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" ng-model="profileData.email" ng-disabled="true" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.password.$invalid && !updateprofileForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Enter a 10 character Password</p>
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="pwd" type="password" ng-model="profileData.password" name="password" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="40" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.confirmpassword.$invalid && !updateprofileForm.confirmpassword.$pristine" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Enter confirm Password</p>
                                <p ng-show="profileData.password !== profileData.confirmpassword && profileData.confirmpassword" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Password does not match</p>
                                <label for="pwd">Confirm Password:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="pwd" type="password" ng-model="profileData.confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="40" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.phone_no.$invalid && !updateprofileForm.phone_no.$pristine" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Enter Valid Phone Number</p>
                                <label for="pwd">Mobile No:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="pwd" type="text" ng-model="profileData.phone_no" name="phone_no" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="40" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group  mg-bseven">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.country_id.$invalid && !updateprofileForm.country_id.$pristine" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Choose a Country Please </p>
                                <label for="country">Country:</label>
                                <select class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 register" name="country_id" ng-change="cities(profileData.country_id)" ng-model="profileData.country_id" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in view_profile" required>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mg-bseven">
                                <p ng-show="updateprofileForm.city_id.$invalid && updateprofileForm.city_id.$dirty" class="help-block color-ferozimp">Choose a City Please</p>
                                <label for="city">City:</label>
                                <select class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 register" name="city_id" ng-disabled="!profileData.country_id || !view_profile" ng-model="profileData.city_id" ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities_data" required>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-seven" ng-init="check = 0">
                                <button type="button" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles,check)"
                                        accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
                                    Select File</button>
                                <br><br>
                                File:
                                <div style="font:smaller">{{f.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}} {{errFile.$errorParam}}
                                    <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
                                        <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%"  
                                             ng-bind="f.progress + '%'" ></div>
                                    </span>
                                </div>     
                                {{errorMsg}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="aa-single-submit mg-bseven">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update profile"  ng-disabled="updateprofileForm.$invalid || fileselected" >Update Profile</button>                  
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `required` from the following line :

```
<input class="form-control" id="pwd" type="password" ng-model="profileData.password" name="password" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="40" required>
```

Comment: now it does not show error if I fill the password field but not confirm password